How to solve Wordpress accordion problem on Iphone?
I have built an accordion FAQ on my WordPress website. It works fine on Desktop, Tablet and Android but on iPhones It does not work properly. To make accordions open and close, weirdly I have to use to fingers. I have tried solutions like manipulating cache plugin and creating accordion with 2 different plugins and even theme widget.
Source page link
The video I have recorded of problem
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?
